# RegEX to capture coordinates followed by a space

Tags: regex

I have code like the following:

```
0.99974 Chr1 3393500 3394000 gene2755 ID=gene2754;Name=FTO;Dbxref=GeneID:101932285;gbkey=Gene;gene=FTO;part=1%21
```

I'm trying to use regular expression to extract only the coordinates (in this case, 3393500 and 3394000.  I'm able to capture the first coordinate, but not both of them.  Any help?

Comment: Language? Sample code? Context (what defines a coordinate in your string(s)?)

Comment: Using Python regex.

Comment: Please give us your regex and code too. It might help. Also give a look at https://regexr.com. This lets you try regex on any text you wish and is sometimes usefull.

Comment: @MaëlPedretti https://regex101.com/ is a better tool since it allows to test for python specifically while regexr only allows PCRE or JavaScript at the moment.

Comment: @ctwheels didn’t know about this one, thanks!

Comment: Thanks so much for regex101.  Took me like two seconds to figure this out!

Comment: @SteveStevemanMan you can post your solution as an answer to your own question on StackOverflow. It may help future readers with similar issues find an appropriate solution. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everybody who recommended regex101.com.  It was extremely easy to use, and I found the following solution to my problem.  This regex worked to capture the coordinates separated by a space:

```
\d{2,}\s\d+
```